# How create endpoint in asp.net core accepting multiple files with a text linked to each file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, iformfile

I want to create a new endpoint in an existing asp.net core API. It should be possible to upload multiple files with a linked text string to each file. I also want to use PostMan to test this endpoint. Is it possible to do this?

This is my C# test code that runs but i don't know how to call it from PostMan:

```
    [HttpPost("upload/test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload([FromForm]UploadModel fileUpload)
    {
        return FileUpload(fileUpload);
    }
```

```
    public class UploadModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Files to upload
        /// </summary>
        public List<FileModel> Files { get; set; }
        public string UploadInfo{ get; set; }
    }

    public class FileModel
    {
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        public string FileText { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing List Object from postman to api, you could try struct like `parameterName[index].fieldName`.

Here is a demo which works for you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, add your text in the **Body->raw**

Then go to **Body->binary->Select file**

[mroe info](https://dev.to/wiaio/upload-a-file-to-wia-via-postman-55ic)

[image]

Comment: It don't work for me when I try it this way. The raw body is:
{
 "files" : [
  {
   "filetext":"My text"
  }
 ],
 "uploadinfo":"Upload info text"
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify controller method to accept multiple form Files as -

   ```
   [HttpPost("upload/test")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
   {
       return await UploadFile(files);
   }
   ```
2. select form-data in postman & send multiple files
   [postman data input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sujy7.png)